# I have a button which I want it to position perfectly with the footer

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, jsx

I have a button which I want it to centered but the position should be right of the footer. I have the done the CSS of footer section but the button is sticking to the bottom. I want it in center like I want the button to move upwards so that it looks like it is positioned perfectly:

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I want it in the center like this:
[image: I want the position to be aligned perfectly]

Here is my code of ReactJS:

```css
.footer__section {
    position: sticky;
    color: lightgray;
    display: flex;
    align-items: right;
    padding: 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
}

.footer__section>form {
    flex: 1;
}

.chat__inputButton {
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div className="footer__section">
   <form>
      <button
         className="chat__inputButton"
         type="submit"
       >
       Send Message
       </button>
   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.footer__section {
    position: sticky;
    color: lightgray;
    display: flex;
    align-items: right;
    justify-content:right;
    padding: 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    border: 1px red solid; // debug
}

.footer__section>form {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;// <- 
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.chat__inputButton {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer__section">
         <form>
            <button
               class="chat__inputButton">Cancel</button>
            <button
               class="chat__inputButton"
               type="submit"
             >
             Send Message
             </button>

         </form>
    </div>
```